# How can you push using git to a Docker Cloud Repo?

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I'm trying to use GIT to push code to Docker Cloud instead of docker push, and get automated builds going?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe docker cloud has the ability to build Dockerfiles?  If I recall correctly, it is for working with already built docker images.  Do you mean [hub.docker](https://hub.docker.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Git push (to either a Github or Bitbucket repo) redeploy one or more services on Docker Cloud by integrating with Docker Hub as jrbeverly mentions.

First, you need to link your Git repo to Docker Hub, so that Docker Hub can build your docker images when you push to your Git repo. There is an introduction on how to make automated builds of Docker images [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/)

Second, you need to setup automatic redeploy of your Docker Cloud service(s) as hinteded at the bottom of [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-redeploy/) and more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/auto-redeploy/).